# Working and creating threads in C but am running into a problem with the argument type

Tags: arrays, c, multithreading, typecasting-operator

I am a bit confused on the formatting that it is looking for and where to implement it.

I keep running into the same waring "warning: passing argument 3 of ‘pthread_create’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

//Run the program without locks and Identify the critical section and write below

/*

*/

//Modify the program with mutex lock to avoid the race condition

pthread_mutex_t lock;

int arr[10];
static int inc;

//start cs
void *incr(int n) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);

    inc=n;

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        arr[i] += n;
        sleep(2);
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
}

//end cs

int main() {
    pthread_t t1, t2;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        arr[i]=1;
        printf("%d", arr[i]);
    }

    pthread_create(&t1,NULL, incr,(void*) 2); //Complete thread creation to pass the value to be incremented in thread 1
    pthread_create(&t2,NULL, incr,(void*) 3); //Complete thread creation to pass the value to be incremented in thread 2

    pthread_join(t1,NULL);
    pthread_join(t2,NULL);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++) //print the array here
    {
        printf("Array[%d] = %d",i,arr[i]);
    }

    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: The function should be `void *incr(void *n)`, no other signatures are allowed

Answer (score 1):

The thread function passed to `pthread_create` is expected to have type `void *(*)(void *)`, i.e. a function that takes a single `void *` parameter and returns a `void *`.  `incr` doesn't match that definition, as its argument has type `int`.

You need to change the function signature to have the type that `pthread_create` expects, then you can convert the parameter inside the function.  The function also needs to return a `void *` which it currently doesn't

So your function should instead look like this:

```
void *incr(void *p) {
    int n = (int)p;
    // do stuff
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain why you are casting `p`, a pointer, directly to an `int`? As I understand it,`n` now holds an address. Wouldn’t you want to dereference `p`: `int n = *(int*)p`?

Comment: @tjcaul — You can more or less get away with the cast because the value passed in the call to `pthread_create()` cast a plain `int` to `(void *)`.  Under stringent compiler warning options, you'd probably want to cast to `uintptr_t` (or `intptr_t`) as an intermediate type: `pthread_create(…, (void *)(uintptr_t)2);` and `int n = (int)(uintptr_t)p;`.  The headers `<stdint.h>` and `<inttypes.h>` define the types.